# Request only works for first item in a loop?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have written a basic script for detecting a like button push for links submitted to my website (like reddit), instantiating a function in my views and returning the like count that is updated. Every single part of the code works fine except that it only works for the first item in the for loop in the template. What am I doing wrong that it cannot capture more than the first element?

My script using jQuery for detecting a button push looks like the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#likes').click(function(){
        var link_id;
        link_id = $(this).attr("data-linkset_id")
        $.get('/uplink/', {linkset_id: link_id}, function(data){
            $('#vote_value').html(data);
            $('#likes').hide();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here's the loop in question with the actual button:

```
{% for link in linkset %}
{{link.url}}
<div id="vote_value">{{link.linklikes}}</div>
<button id ="likes" data-linkset_id="{{link.id}}" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type="button">like</button>
{% endfor %}
```

And here's the function in my views.py that takes a newlink object and changes its like count then returns that updated integer:

```
def uplink(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    link_id = None
        if request.method == 'GET':
        link_id = request.GET['linkset_id']

    likes = 0
    if link_id:
        thelink = newlink.objects.get(id=int(link_id))
        if thelink:
            likes = thelink.linklikes + 1
            thelink.linklikes = likes
            thelink.save()

    return HttpResponse(likes)
```

Really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`id`s must be unique on a page. Only one element can have a certain `id`. Change the `id` attribute and selector to a class or data attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-role=like_container]').on('click', '[data-action=like_button]', function(e){
        var $like_container = $(e.delegateTarget);
        var $like_button = $(e.currentTarget);
        var $vote_value = $like_container.find('[data-role=vote_value]');
        var link_id = $like_button.data("linkset_id");
        $.get('/uplink/', {linkset_id: link_id}, function(uplink_response){
            $vote_value.html(uplink_response);
            $like_button.hide();
        });
    });
});
```

---

```
{% for link in linkset %}
<div data-role="like_container">
  {{link.url}}
  <div data-role="vote_value">{{link.linklikes}}</div>
  <button data-action="like_button" data-linkset_id="{{link.id}}" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type="button">like</button>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Not really even sure I understand what extra js you wrote means such as the $(e.delegateTarget) and $(e.currentTarget), but I'll do some research and try to replicate it. I appreciate your answer!